# Do VMware, Virtualbox & Virtual PC play nicely together?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware-player, microsoft-virtual-pc

Lately VirtualBox has been a bit unstable and I want to try other VMs.

If I install VMware and Virtual PC on the same host as VirtualBox will it cause problems (eg. crash the host)? What if I try to run two of them at once?

I'm concerned because I know they all install kernel-mode drivers. Even if I disable hardware virtualization I'm sure there's potential for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I've had VMWare and Virtual PC working nicely on the same Windows host, but I have not tried to install VirtualBox on the same machine. I did, however, have VirtualBox running on a Windows 2008 Server with Windows Hyper-V without any problems.

Now I only use VMWare Workstation though, since it I find that far better than the the other two alternatives you are mentioning. I believe with VMWare Converter you can import both VirtualBox and Virtual PC images into VMWare.